Resolving conflicts
Is there any mentioned in the sutras about specific approaches to resolving conflicts? Specifically, I am looking at applying an objective process. For example, if a person disagrees with another on the interpretation of a passage in the sutra, one way is to look at the Pali translation as an objective approach.
I am looking at a generic approach, one that presumably can be prescribed to resolve other disputes/conflicts in life. It might consist of a series of prescriptive steps. I understand that the attitude we take is equally important as mentioned in these answers (1 and 2).
Lastly, I believe if such an objective process/approach is possible, it would develop one's ability to self-correct one’s own wrong views and positions. The rationale is that wrong views do lead us to wrong places (SN56.43).
Appendix A (extracted from answer)
If views/positions are not in accordance with accepted rules, prevailing standards and general morality, they are outright considered wrong.
Where this is not obvious, the following steps can be prescribed:

Having acceptable ombudsmen/mediators or umpires/referees to the disputing parties.

Decision via majority or consensus (preferably consisting of experts in the subject matter).


Parties involved in conflict/dispute should process presence of mind, be conscientious and truthful. In addition, they should not:

be easily angered or vengeful
be spiteful or vindictive
be jealous and possessive
be scheming and deceitful
be obstinate

Factors to consider before engaging in conflict/dispute resolution

appropriate time (and place)
matter should concern something factual
resolution should be fruitful and beneficial
follow the spirit rather than the letter



The Vinaya has a set of procedures designed to help monks resolve conflicts. They're called adhikaraṇasamathadhammā: "principles for settling issues."
https://www.dhammatalks.org/vinaya/bmc/Section0027.html
See further this excellent essay on the topic by Ven. Ṭhānissaro, showing how these and other methods from the Vinaya can be used as a model for conflict-resolution in any community:

"To encourage right reconciliation among his followers, the Buddha
formulated detailed methods for achieving it, along with a culture of
values that encourages putting those methods to use.
The methods are contained in the Vinaya, the Buddha’s code of monastic
discipline. Long passages in the Vinaya are devoted to instructions
for how monks should confess their offenses to one another, how they
should seek reconciliation with lay people they have wronged, how they
should settle protracted disputes, and how a full split in the
Sangha—the monastic community—should be healed. Although directed to
monks, these instructions embody principles that apply to anyone
seeking reconciliation of differences, whether personal or political."

Reconciliation - Right & Wrong

+1 that the Vinaya contained procedures to resolve disputes. I have tried to summarized what is written in the references, please provide any comment/feedback in the added materials, thanks!

Assuming you are asking about conflicts that spring from conversations on the true meaning of Buddhist teachings.
Above all, I think, every party of conversation must remember that the Path culminates in raising above all positions, because any bounded position would be partial, and the danger of attachment to partial position is entanglement and clashing conducive to suffering.
Therefore, the ultimate arbiter or mediator should not be the objectivity or morality (because with them we still are in danger of circular argument what exactly should be considered objective or moral etc). Nor can the EBTs (Early Buddhist Texts, such as the Pali Canon) be the arbiter, because people tend to disagree on the exact interpretation of the texts. Instead, the final arbiter IMO should be the open mind of dispassion and non-attachment.
As said in Sutta Nipata 4.9:

Asking questions dependent on view, you’re confused by the things you have grasped
...
Those who grasp at interpretations [saññā] & views go about clashing in the world.

Also, SN 22.3

And how does one not engage with people in quarrelsome debate? There is the case where a certain person is NOT a fomenter of this kind of debate: ‘You understand this doctrine & discipline? I’m the one who understands this doctrine & discipline. How could you understand this doctrine & discipline? You’re practicing wrongly. I’m practicing rightly. What should be said first you said last. What should be said last you said first. I’m being consistent. You’re not. What you took so long to think out has been refuted. Your doctrine has been overthrown. You’re defeated. Go and try to salvage your doctrine, or extricate yourself if you can!’

Famously, MN 72:

Does Master Gotama have any position, any view at all?
Vaccha, a ‘position’ is something that Tathagata has done away with.

Instead, MN 22:

The Dhamna is taught for the elimination of all view-positions, determinations, biases, inclinations, & obsessions; for the pacification of all fabrications; for the relinquishing of all acquisitions; the ending of craving; dispassion; cessation; unbinding.

When all parties of the conversation keep this in mind, this creates the right context that precludes formation of quarrelsome debates and helps with the right interpretation of the teaching.

+1 for the reminder on the ultimate goal. Actually, it is not just w.r.t. disputes on Buddhist teachings but I am hoping the approach is applicable to various conflicts as there are so many in life. Point noted on the potentially diverse interpretations on Buddhist texts. Perhaps, my example is not a good one. If you can bear with me, I was wondering since differing views/positions lead to distinct results, would that be a good criteria for resolving conflicts?

Your saying "partial" positions reminds me of the parable of the blind men and the elephant -- which I think is a good depiction of a problem, i.e. of the resulting symptoms (conflict about views), and of the cause? I'm not sure I see what you're saying next  though, i.e. "open mind of dispassion and non-attachment". Instead of one-sided I might be many-sided --"Yes it is like a sail, yes it is like a tree trunk, yes, yes there is truth in what you say, how exciting!" -- which, I'm not sure, doesn't seem like what you were saying.

I guess I'm saying "open mind of dispassion and non-attachment" (incl. wrt views and interpretations!) is the goal of all Buddhist teaching, everything else is just scaffolding. If we keep this in mind when having our debates, things will get much easier than if we try to use moral, objectivity, orthodoxy, and other such criteria to help navigate the debate. My answer was in context of Buddhist debates only, not all conflicts in general.

I agree with your point about dispassion/non-attachment. Living in society with its strive for profits, power and influence, we sometimes end up with the lesser evil by relying on something that appears neutral, objective and majority driven in order to resolve conflicting positions/interests/views. Even in such cases, reading the Vinaya linked, I see there are, nevertheless, attempts to subvert the process....ah, humans!
